# Adding one column or variable year to multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, multiple-columns, addition

I am new to R. Let me explain what I want to do. To summarize my process, I want to add a column called year to 8 data frames with values ranging from 2015 to 2022. Meaning, add the value 2015 to df1, 2016 to df2, 2017 to df3 etc....
I tried doing this on Python which was so easy , but R just give me errors.
**Here is what I tried on R,

```
`  years <- (2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022) `
'  df_list <- (df1, df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8)`

' for (i in 1:8){

  df[i]$Year <- years[i]}'
```

Comment: `Map(replace, df_list, "year", years)` or if you must use a loop - `for(i in seq_along(years)) { df_list[[i]][["year"]] <- years[i] }`

Comment: `df_list <- Map(transform, df_list, Year = unlist(years))`

Comment: Thank you , God bless you. I just had to transform it into a vector and mind my list notation. Thank you ,thank you.